# Using DocuSign api in an online angular application without proxy server

Tags: docusignapi

i have read a lot about DocuSign api and how they works, i figured out that they don't support cors.
For this reason i'm using an angular proxy configuration for my test environment, so i could do all my tests with my localhost.

The problem is that when i upload my project on a server i can no more use that proxy config, if i try to use it by replacing "localhost" with my domain name it returns me an html which is not an error from docusign but a sort of error related to my proxy conf.

I think i need create a cors gateway in my server in order to use the api, i've read a guide about that and it's very complicated since i'm only a frontend developer.
So my answer is:
is there any easier method to use these api in my online application?
can i obtain some sort of permissions from docusign which grants to my domaint to access their api calls without going into some sort of cors errors.

Thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

I work in DocuSign developer support. We do not support CORS. It is on our roadmap. Looks like you have your options, move the calls to DocuSign to the back-end or build a CORS gateway.